# WebDriver - Having a plugin run when running a webdriver/selenium test

Tags: internet-explorer, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I've got a set of selenium tests that fireup pages that have Silverlight Objects on them. I've got script that interacts with the silverlight object and captures the results.

These tests seem fine on FireFox but I can't seem to get the Silverlight object loaded when internet explorer 8 runs.

I got around my initial problem (my ability to change IE on the box is limited) by doing the following:

```
 var capabilities = new OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DesiredCapabilities();

        capabilities.SetCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings, true);

        Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```

This got around the fact that protected mode is not the same across zones.

It turns out that the buildserver is launching the 64bit version of IE which Silverlight 4 doesn't support.

So the question now is whether there is a way of forcing the test to use the 32bit version?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0):

The way to resolve this issue is to configure your buildserver to run the test harness (in my case NUnit) in 32bit mode.

Selenium webdriver then launches the 32bit version of IE and Silverlight runs.